# Solving system of equations including numerical integrals over region

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, regions

I am dealing with the resolution of a concrete beam. Simply put, it is an equilibrium of horizontal forces and moments.

Let's first define some parameters :

```
h = 300;

(*Concrete parameters*)
ETS = 34000;
fTSc = -20;
fTSt = 2.262;
eTSc = fTSc/ETS;
eTSt = fTSt/ETS;
ec1 = 2/1000;
ec2 = 3/1000;

(*Steel parameters*)
fsy = 435;
Es = 205000;
```

Let's define the constitutive laws for concrete and steel :

```
σTS[eTS_] := 
  Piecewise[{
   {fTSc*(-(ETS/(400*fTSc))*-eTS/ec1 - (-eTS/ec1)^2)/(1 + (ETS/(-400*fTSc) - 2)*-eTS/ec1), 
0 > eTS >= -2/1000},
   {fTSc, -ec1 > eTS >= -ec2},
   {ETS*eTS, 0 < eTS < eTSt}
  }]

σS[es_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {Es*es, -fsy/Es <= es <= fsy/Es},
    {-fsy, -45/1000 < es < -fsy/Es},
    {fsy, fsy/Es < es < 45/1000 }
  }]

 Plot[σTS[x], {x, -ec2, eTSt}, PlotRange -> Full]
 Plot[σS[x], {x, -45/1000, 45/1000}]

 e[hi_] := -chi*hi + chi (h - xn);

 σTS = σTS[e[hi]]
 σS = σS[e[hi]]
```

Now we define the global geometry of the beam :

```
XYTS = {{0, 0}, {200, 0}, {200, 300}, {0, 300}};
ΩTS = {Polygon[XYTS]};
XYArmatureTS = {{{30, 30}, 20.0}, {{170, 30},20.0}};
ΩSTS = Table[Disk[XYArmatureTS[[i, 1]], XYArmatureTS[[i, 2]]/2], {i, 1, Length@XYArmatureTS}];
Graphics[{LightGray, ΩTS, Black, ΩSTS}]
```

which gives the following result (concrete section with two steel region) :

[image: a gray rectangle with two small black circles along the bottom edge]

I want to make regions which I can integrate over:

```
MakeRegion[obj_] := Map[Region[#] &, obj]; 
ΩMat = Table[MakeRegion[i], {i, {ΩTS, ΩSTS}}];
ΩTS = RegionDifference[ΩMat[[1, 1]], RegionUnion[ΩMat[[2]]]];
ΩS = RegionUnion[ΩMat[[2, 1]], ΩMat[[2, 2]]];
```

I create two function `NTot` (normal force) and `MTot` (moment) which take `chi` and `xn` as arguments. I want to solve these two functions as a system of equations with `NSolve` or `FindRoot`...

```
NTot[CHI_?NumericQ, XN_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[σTS /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN},{x, y} ∈ ΩTS] + 
  NIntegrate[σS /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, y} ∈ ΩS]

MTot[CHI_?NumericQ, XN_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[y*σTS /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, y} ∈ ΩTS] + 
  NIntegrate[y*σS /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, y} ∈ ΩS]

Nd=0;
Md=40*10^-6;

FindRoot[{NTot[x, y] == Nd, MTot[x, y] == -Md}, {{x, 1*10^-6}, {y, 80}}]
```

As you will notice, it fails.
The two functions `NTot` and `MTot` work well if I manually specify solutions as follows:

```
(*For Md=-40*10^6 and Nd = 0*)
sol1 = 7.40246874*10^-6;
sol2 = 92.46126;
NTot[sol1, sol2]       (* Out:  -8.399*)
MTot[sol1, sol2]/10^6  (* Out: -40.08 *)

(*For Md=-55*10^6 and Nd=0*)
sol1 = 10.82*10^-6;
sol2 = 99.55203;
NTot[sol1, sol2]       (* Out:  16.19*)
MTot[sol1, sol2]/10^6  (* Out: -55.17*)
```

I don't need much precision for these calculations, I would say for `NTot`, I must reach `NTot(chi,xn) = Nd +- 200` and `MTot(chi,xn) = Md +- 0.5`.

Any idea how to solve this particular system of equations?

Comment: What are the numerical values of `Nd` and `Md`? I can't find their definition in your code, and that makes the `FindRoot` expression symbolic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will update my post, it is confusing. `Nd` and `Md` can take any real value, for this example we limit ourselves to `Nd=0` and `Md = -40*10^6`

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem as optimization problem as follows

```
h = 300;

(*Concrete parameters*)
ETS = 34000;
fTSc = -20;
fTSt = 2.262;
eTSc = fTSc/ETS;
eTSt = fTSt/ETS;
ec1 = 2/1000;
ec2 = 3/1000;

(*Steel parameters*)
fsy = 435;
Es = 205000;
\[Sigma]TS[eTS_] := 
  Piecewise[{{fTSc*(-(ETS/(400*fTSc))*-eTS/
           ec1 - (-eTS/ec1)^2)/(1 + (ETS/(-400*fTSc) - 2)*-eTS/ec1), 
     0 > eTS >= -2/1000}, {fTSc, -ec1 > eTS >= -ec2}, {ETS*eTS, 
     0 < eTS < eTSt}}];

\[Sigma]S[es_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Es*es, -fsy/Es <= es <= fsy/Es}, {-fsy, -45/1000 < 
      es < -fsy/Es}, {fsy, fsy/Es < es < 45/1000}}];

Plot[\[Sigma]TS[x], {x, -ec2, eTSt}, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[\[Sigma]S[x], {x, -45/1000, 45/1000}]

e[hi_] := -chi*hi + chi (h - xn);

\[Sigma]TS = \[Sigma]TS[e[hi]]
\[Sigma]S = \[Sigma]S[e[hi]]
XYTS = {{0, 0}, {200, 0}, {200, 300}, {0, 300}};
\[CapitalOmega]TS = {Polygon[XYTS]};
XYArmatureTS = {{{30, 30}, 20.0}, {{170, 30}, 20.0}};
\[CapitalOmega]STS = 
  Table[Disk[XYArmatureTS[[i, 1]], XYArmatureTS[[i, 2]]/2], {i, 1, 
    Length@XYArmatureTS}];
Graphics[{LightGray, \[CapitalOmega]TS, Black, \[CapitalOmega]STS}]
MakeRegion[obj_] := Map[Region[#] &, obj];
\[CapitalOmega]Mat = 
  Table[MakeRegion[i], {i, {\[CapitalOmega]TS, \[CapitalOmega]STS}}];
\[CapitalOmega]TS = 
  RegionDifference[\[CapitalOmega]Mat[[1, 1]], 
   RegionUnion[\[CapitalOmega]Mat[[2]]]];
\[CapitalOmega]S = 
  RegionUnion[\[CapitalOmega]Mat[[2, 1]], \[CapitalOmega]Mat[[2, 2]]];
With[{op = 3}, 
 NTot[CHI_?NumericQ, XN_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[\[Sigma]TS /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, 
      y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]TS, AccuracyGoal -> op, 
    PrecisionGoal -> op] + 
   NIntegrate[\[Sigma]S /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, 
      y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]S];
 
 MTot[CHI_?NumericQ, XN_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
    y*\[Sigma]TS /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, 
      y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]TS, AccuracyGoal -> op, 
    PrecisionGoal -> op] + 
   NIntegrate[
    y*\[Sigma]S /. {hi -> y, chi -> CHI, xn -> XN}, {x, 
      y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]S];]

Nd = 0;
Md = 40*10^-6;
```

If we try to solve this problem with `FindRoot` then we have

```
  FindRoot[{NTot[x1, y1] == Nd, 
  MTot[x1, y1] == -Md}, {{x1, 1*10^-6}, {y1, 80}}]
```

There is a message

```
During evaluation of In[35]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x1,y1} = {0.000701094,-515.205}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

Out[35]= {x1 -> 0.000701094, y1 -> -515.205}
```

We can compute optimal solution as follows

```
F = {NTot[x1, y1] - Nd, MTot[x1, y1] + Md};
    
    NMinimize[F . F, {x1, y1}]
    
(*{1.6*10^-9, {x1 -> 32.0751, y1 -> -1.68373}}*)
```

We can plot function `F.F` to visualize solution computed with `NMinimize`

```
Plot3D[F . F, {x1, -1, 40}, {y1, -5, 5}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
Show[%, 
 Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
   Cone[{{32.07506783687917`, -1.683732564523424`, 
      3 10^4}, {32.07506783687917`, -1.683732564523424`, 
      1.6000000000000003`*^-9}}, .2]}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]